# Display data in GridView according to priority

Tags: c#, database

i am stuck with some thing like

I want to retrieve records from a table which having fields like id ,priority and txt.

```
id         priority    txt
5            1          Hello how are you? (recently added with the 1 priority)
3            1          I am fine
2            1          where are from 
4            2          Yes (recently added with the 2 priority)
1            2          No
```

I want to show in the Grid View as (recently added record should be on top if the priority is same than next with the same priority so on) i don't want to use date time column for that. is it possible? via (Sql query) or (C# code)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the exact same result above, try the query

```
select id, priority, txt from table order by priority ASC, id DESC
```